# In XQuery 3.0 (zorba) how can you get the results of updating operations inside a tag

Tags: xquery, updating, zorba

I have to make multiple calls to a Xquery server in a single request (to enable a transaction behavior). It's something like this

```
declare namespace foo = "ns.bar.foo";
( foo:call("toto"), foo:call("tata"), foo:call("titi"))
```

But if I do that, the server returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<call-result> 1 </call-result>
<call-result> 2 </call-result>
<call-result> 3 </call-result>
```

Which is not a valid XML file because the results are not inside a root tag.
My first try was something like

```
declare namespace foo = "ns.bar.foo";
<results> {( foo:call("toto"), foo:call("tata"), foo:call("titi"))} </results>
```

But since foo:call is an updating expression, it's not allowed.The only thing I see is to modify the received XML on the client side but that's really dirty.
I could also add a method on the server side, like a foo:calls, but foo:call already works with sequences as a parameter, and you cannot have sequences of sequences in xQuery. Any suggestion?

Comment: How does Zorba return anything in an updating expression? This is actually not allowed according to the spec, but many processors user some extension to enable this. I guess you could do it there, so you might want to show your `foo:call` function. Also, I see no reason why your first try should not work. It is certainly possible to have multiple updating expressions in a sequence based on the specifications. I would be interested why this is disallowed in Zorba.

Comment: I reached the conclusion that it's in fact not a good practice to return something in an updating expression. So instead, I get the results after the "foo:call" with a classic reading expression. It's working (though, I might say, I have no idea why, I thought the modifications would be applied at the end of the transaction, when it's too late because the reading call has already been made).

Comment: It would be interesting to see your actual code. You are correct, because of the PUL of XQuery Update all updates are apoplied after read operations. What we usually do is to compute our new or updated element in main memory (using transform expressions) then put this element into the database and returning it as well. I wouldn't cosider this bad practice.